# How to view the full path of a file in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb

When I stop at a break point in gdb, it just shows the filename.cpp. How can I view the full pathname of this file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `info source` command to get info for the current stack frame.

Here is an example of its output:

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is /build/gtk+2.0-LJ3oCC/gtk+2.0-2.24.30/modules/input/gtkimcontextxim.c
Located in /home/sashoalm/Desktop/compile/gtk+2.0-2.24.30/modules/input/gtkimcontextxim.c
Contains 1870 lines.
Source language is c.
Producer is GNU C11 5.3.1 20160225 -mtune=generic -march=i686 -g -g -O2 -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

Comment: This command displays information about the *current* breakpoint, and sometimes it takes a long time to hit a breakpoint on a specific function. On this cases may be useful to force a jump to that function with `jump <function_name>`.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent answer from Ciro Santill. However, the script needed a small correction to work with my gdb 8.0.1.

I also changed it to copy the text to the clipboard so I can use it in vim straight away. It works nicely with [file_line.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin. This is an example of the clipboard content produced by the script:

```
/home/ops1/projects/test01/main.cpp:5
```

The script is below:

```
import pyperclip

class Clippath (gdb.Command):
    """print absolute path"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Clippath, self).__init__("clippath", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        symtabline = gdb.selected_frame().find_sal()
        pyperclip.copy(symtabline.symtab.fullname() + ":" + str(symtabline.line))

Clippath()
```

Here are the steps to make it all work:

1. Install pyperclip python library
   sudo zypper in python3-pyperclip
2. Save the script above to a file, say file-path.py and copy it to ~/.gdb
3. Update ~/.gdbinit with adding the following lines:
   source ~/.gdb/file-path.py
4. Now you can copy the path and line to the clipboard with `clippath` in gdb

And read more about GDB Python API - [link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API)

Comment: A related lightweight vim approach that opens vim directly on the shell at the correct line: https://github.com/cirosantilli/dotfiles/blob/750aa4e4ad8280a960bd0f0fe883921af5770068/home/.gdbinit.py#L275

Answer (score 2):

**In Python scripting**

To learn Python scripting, or if you want to see just the full path and nothing else:

```
class Curpath(gdb.Command):
    """
Print absolute path of the current file.
"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('curpath', gdb.COMMAND_FILES)
    def invoke(self, argument, from_tty):
        gdb.write(gdb.selected_frame().find_sal().symtab.fullname() + os.linesep)
Curpath()
```

Usage:

```
curpath
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filename-display` to control how file names are displayed in GDB. To display absolute filenames use the following command in the beginning of GDB session:

```
set filename-display absolute
```

See [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html). This option appeared since GDB 7.6.